# How to handle browser_close event using selenium

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

1.) Hi, I want to log a fatal error message using log4j when the browser is closed manually, while selenium's automated testing is in process. Is there any way out for it?

2.) Also calling driver.close() or driver.quit() doesn't close my chromedriver. I have to manually close the chromedriver.exe task from the TaskManager. Do let me know the reason and a way out for this too.

Thanks in advance

Comment: What version of ChromeDriver & Chrome is it? You should be using `.quit`.

Comment: Chrome Version 25.0.1364.97  and ChromeDriver 26.0.1383.0

Comment: driver.quit is not working for me and i have to perform regress testing, so at the end of the day there are around 70-80 drivers running in my TaskManager.. Pls help

Comment: Put a small reproducible case in your question. As in, make a very very simple test, just a few lines, with `driver.quit()` at the end, and see if the same thing happens - if so, put that code in your question.